# Disable scroll wheel on the Google Maps on Careers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, scrolling

It is very annoying when I'm trying to scroll down the page and then at one point I'm just zooming out on the map and in order to continue scrolling I have to move away with the mouse (and if I actually wanted to check the map I have to zoom back in).

All the buttons are there to be able to zoom out if you really want to so there is no need to have that flag enabled.

All you have to do is to [`scrollwheel: false`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2330272/8418).

Here is an example http://careers.stackoverflow.com/company/stack-exchange

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That mouse wheeling thing was indeed annoying. We disabled it throughout the site.

Thanks for your report! Gotta love it when our users not only suggest improvements to our sites but also send us the code that implements them! <3

Comment: I had a similar issue with one of my own apps :) thanks